# Angular Router changes state but url doesnt change

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to create an application whose state is represented in the URL directly by using paramters. One of those parameters should be a selection criterion where multiple items can be selected. Changing the selection means that items get added or removed from that list in the url parameters. That means that the list from the parameters have to be known at the point where i want to change it.

The Problem is that in the case where i change the url parameters while I am subscribed to them the url doesnt change. I made i minimal example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slnewb). I can provide some code inside this question but i think the demo is sufficient.

I figured out that the problem might be that i need to subscribe to the parameters before adding them. So i tried to build some kind of caching mechanism that stores the list in a variable. If i use that variable instead of the parameters directly it kind of works. But this is some kind of workaround that creates other problems.

Moreover if i have a second parameter that is not a list and i change that one all the changes that have been made to the list parameter will be shown in the url as expected.

Feel free to ask me anythink if you dont understand my problem.

Edit1: If you check my demo there is a button. And i expect that if you click the button a parameter will be added to the url. Each time the button is clicked another parameter should be added that the url looks like this: `https://angular-slnewb.stackblitz.io/?myParameter=0&myParameter=1`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. provide a code here mentioning that you tried this and you want output A, but instead you're getting another output B. It'll help others in understanding your requirement in a better way. English language is not always a good depiction of showing what you want to achieve in code.

Comment: @Hemendra You can check the link to my demo. There is all the code that i have in a minimal example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slnewb).

Comment: you are passing empty array in the route.navigate, so it's not changing route and it not refreshing the page as well.

Comment: I have checked it already, but your description of the problem is not clear and not able to follow on what exactly you have tried and where it's failing you.

Comment: @virendernehra i dont think thats the problem because i pass the parameters in form of customQueryParams. And those work the first time it is executed.

Comment: @Hemendra I am trying to add an element to a url parameter. That means i have an array as parameter and each time i change some thing (button click) one item should be added to this array. But as you can see in the example the url doesnt shot all the elements that are contained in this array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try convert the array to string.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyDataService {
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  public getMyUrlParameter(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(map(params => {
      const myParameter = params["myParameter"];
      return myParameter ? myParameter.split(',') : [];
    }));
  }

  public setMyUrlParameter(myParameter: string[]): void {
    const customQueryParams = {};
    customQueryParams["myParameter"] = myParameter.toString();
    this.router.navigate([], {
      queryParams: customQueryParams,
      // preserve the existing query params in the route
      queryParamsHandling: "merge"
    });
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-negcsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-data.service.ts

Comment: Yeah i thought about that solution as well earlier but that doesnt explain what using the regular array doesnt work. So if nobody has any idea i might just go with you answer.

Comment: You're only converting the array as string and assigning it to queryParams. @Tobias you want the output in this way - myParameter=0&myParameter=1 but instead it'll show the output like this - myParameter=0,1,2,3

Comment: @Hemendra Exactly thats what i want.

Comment: @Tobias Any help for you? https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L404

Comment: @HsuanLee i did took i look but i dont think that this is actually the problem. Becaus if you try setting an array as url parameter directly without reading it from the url parameters before it simply works. My guess is that there might be a problem with this special case where i have to read the parameter before i can write it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, the issue in the example you've provided is that on click of button you're not really navigating to a different page. It's the same route always. When you change the routes in `setParameter` method, it merges the queryParams values

```
public setMyUrlParameter(url: string, myParameter: string[]): void {
    const customQueryParams: Params = {};
    customQueryParams["myParameter"] = myParameter;
    this.router.navigate([url], {
      queryParams: customQueryParams,
      // preserve the existing query params in the route
      queryParamsHandling: "merge"
    });
  }
```

I've created a working fork here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-routing-tn8av4

Comment: Actually I dont want to navigate to a different page. I want to stay on the same page and change the parameters.

Comment: I think it's either an expected behavior or a bug on Angular side itself. If we're updating the value of the queryParams, it's updating in the URL. But if we are appending any new value in the existing array of queryParams, it's not reflecting those. I've updated my fork, I'm assigning a new random value everytime I click on "About" and it's getting updated on the URL.

Comment: I think thats the point if i am writing a new value it works just fine (for arrays as well as for strings) but if i am reading the parameter before it doesnt work.